# Codeigniter Call Parent Controller Function Inside Model

Tags: php, codeigniter, inheritance

I know this is MVC structure incompatible but i need to use this technique:

I have a controller and a model.

I'm calling a function in model from controller.

Model called function calles controllers another function. (This is what generates error).

Example below:

Controller:

```
public function B($ret=false) {
    if(!$ret)$this->Model_model->M($ret);
    else echo 'ok';
    }
```

Model:

```
public function M($ret=false) {
    $this->N($ret);
    }

private function N($ret=false) {
    $this->Controller->B(!$ret); //i can't find how can i call this
    }
```

My first trigger function is:

```
$this->Controller->B(false);
```

Comment: i've simplified my real functions. They are very long and i don't want to keep long functions in controller and want to keep them in model.

If can't find a solution i know i need to move B function in controller.

Comment: You should better make a controller function a bit longer than use a bad practice imho.

Comment: i know this @YellowBird. I've changed my structure little; you can see above code. Are there any solution for this?

Comment: calling a function from ctrl in model is just wrong! If you need create "abstract" class for all your models and have a file with functions that are accessible by every model (if you wish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've moved code in function B of controller to the Model completely and now everything is going in model itself. B function calling another B function in model and at last step model isn't need to call controller; it is calling B function in Model:

Controller:

```
public function B($ret=false) {
    $this->Model_model->B($ret);
    }
```

Model:

```
public function B($ret){
    if(!$ret)$this->M($ret);
    else echo 'ok';
    }

private function M($ret=false) {
    $this->N($ret);
    }

private function N($ret=false) {
    $this-B(!$ret);
    }
```

My first trigger function is:

```
$this->B(false);
```

And my controller is still has short code.